# Use directive with required ^form in an angular-material md-dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-material, angular-directive

> Plunker available [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqKvGY?editors=1010)

I want to include a directive (*first* directive in the example) with a required `^form` in an angular-material md-dialog.
When the dialog is shown, there's an error saying the form can't be found:

```
[$compile:ctreq] Controller 'form', required by directive 'first', can't be found!
```

I'm using `require:^form` because I want to validate with `ng-messages` some fields of the parent form inside the directive. The directive outside the dialog works as expected and the form input is validated correctly, the problem is only happening when I use the directive inside the dialog.

I've tried to include another directive (*second* directive in the example), without `require:^form`, and it's displayed correctly in the dialog, but in this case the input cannot be validated.

My question is: is there any way to use a directive with "form required" in a md-dialog when the form is defined outside of the dialog?

I suppose it's because mdDialog is creating its own scope... I've tried passing the current scope, creating a new one, etc. but without success so far.

The problem can be easily reproduced in the attached plunker.

Relevant source for reference:

```
function first() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        param: '@'
      },
      require: '^form',
      bindToController: true,
      template: '<md-input-container class="md-block"><label>Street with validation</label><input name="street" ng-model="vm.street" required><div ng-messages="form.street.$error"><div ng-message="required">Required</div></div></md-input-container>',
      controller: FirstController,
      controllerAs: 'first',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, form) {
        scope.form = form;
      }
    };

    FirstController.$inject = [];

    function FirstController() {
      var first = this;
    }
    return directive;
  }


function openDialogFail(event) {
  $mdDialog.show({
    template: '<md-dialog><md-dialog-content><first/></md-dialog-content></md-dialog>',
    targetEvent: event,
    controller: () => this //,
      // scope: $scope.$new()
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you wanna achieve but sth like this http://codepen.io/z00bs/pen/VadJxV?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to achieve exactly the behaviour of your plunker. However, in your example the form is inside the dialog content and in my question the form is placed in the view where the dialog is opened (because there are other inputs of the same form outside of the dialog). I've forked your plunker [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyKXGe), moving the form, and the problem still remains...

Comment: I still don't get the use case but does something stop you from wrapping `<first />` within a separate `<form>`like in http://codepen.io/z00bs/pen/vGaBgm?

Comment: Thanks again. To be honest, I took for granted that this should be posible using just one form and I dismissed other possibilities, my bad. Reconsidering my use case, I think you're right and there is no problem in using a separate form for the dialog. If you post an answer with the last plunker, I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracted from comments:

> I still don't get the use case but does something stop you from wrapping `<first />` within a separate `<form>` like in [codepen.io/z00bs/pen/vGaBgm](http://codepen.io/z00bs/pen/vGaBgm)